# How to say to foreign key model to use the same database as main model uses?

Tags: django, django-models

I ran into a case when model and fireign key model are both referencing to one DB but DB isn't default.

F.e.

```
class Ref(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()

class Main(class.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    ref_id = models.ForeignKey(Ref)
...........

qs = models.Main.object.using('custom_db').all()
```

Django attemps to get foreign key from **default** database and expectially catches an exception 'table or view doesnt exist'

Is there a simple way to say to foreign key model use the same database as Main ? 
Thanks

Comment: I think django doesn't support relationship that span to multiple database.


`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830564/how-to-use-django-models-with-foreign-keys-in-different-dbs`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
class Main(class.Model):
    ...
```

to

```
class Main(models.Model):
    ...
```

As the `Main` class isn't subclassing a Django model, it's not being created in the database. Hence why you have the `Ref` table being created in the database, but the `table or view doesnt exist` for the `Main` class.