# "Matching"/relations data across databases in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In developing a website for indexing system documentation I've come across a tough nut to crack regarding data "matching"/relations across databases in Django.

A simplified model for my local database:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    system_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Imagined model, system details are stored in a remote database.

```
from django.db import models               

class System(models.Model):     
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)           
    system_id = models.IntegerField()      
    ...
```

The idea is that when creating a new Document entry at my website the ID of the related system is to be stored in the local database. When presenting the data I would have to use the stored ID to retrieve the system name among other details from the remote database.

I've looked into [foreign keys across databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493241/how-to-work-around-lack-of-support-for-foreign-keys-across-databases-in-django), but this seems to be very extensive and I'm not sure if I want relations. Rather I visualize a function inside the Document model/class which is able to retrieve the matching data, for example by importing a custom router/function.

How would I go about solving this?

---

Note that I won't be able to alter anything on the remote database, and it's read-only. Not sure if I should create a model for System aswell. Both databases use PostgreSQL, however my impression is that it's not really of relevance to this scenario which database is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the django documentation [multi-db (manually-selecting-a-database)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)

```
# This will run on the 'default' database.
Author.objects.all()

# So will this.
Author.objects.using('default').all()

# This will run on the 'other' database.
Author.objects.using('other').all()

The 'default' and 'other' are aliases for you databases.
In your case it would could be 'default' and 'remote'.
```

of course you could replace the .all() with anything you want.

```
Example: System.objects.using('remote').get(id=123456)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that foreign keys across databases are a problem in Django ORM, and to some extent at the db level too.

You already have the answer basically: *"I visualize a function inside the Document model/class which is able to retrieve the matching data"*

I'd do it like this:

```
class RemoteObject(object):
    def __init__(self, remote_model, remote_db, field_name):
        # assumes remote db is defined in Django settings and has an
        # associated Django model definition:
        self.remote_model = remote_model
        self.remote_db = remote_db
        # name of id field on model (real db field):
        self.field_name = field_name
        # we will cache the retrieved remote model on the instance
        # the same way that Django does with foreign key fields:
        self.cache_name = '_{}_cache'.format(field_name)

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        try:
            rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
        except AttributeError:
            system_id = getattr(instance, self.field_name)
            remote_qs = self.remote_model.objects.using(self.remote_db)
            try:
                rel_obj = remote_qs.get(id=system_id)
            except self.remote_model.DoesNotExist:
                rel_obj = None
            setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)
        if rel_obj is None:
            raise self.related.model.DoesNotExist
        else:
            return rel_obj

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self.field_name, value.id)
        setattr(instance, self.cache_name, value)


class Document(models.Model:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    system_id = models.IntegerField()
    system = RemoteObject(System, 'system_db_name', 'system_id')
```

You may recognise that the `RemoteObject` class above implements Python's descriptor protocol, see here for more info:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

Example usage:

```
>>> doc = Document.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> print doc.system_id
3
>>> print doc.system.id
3
>>> print doc.system.name
'my system'
>>> other_system = System.objects.using('system_db_name').get(pk=5)
>>> doc.system = other_system
>>> print doc.system_id
5
```

Going further you could write a custom db router:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers

This would let you eliminate the `using('system_db_name')` calls in the code by routing all reads for `System` model to the appropriate db.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a method get_system(). So:

```
class Document:
    def get_system(self):
       return System.objects.using('remote').get(system_id=self.system_id)
```

This is the simplest solution. A possible solution is also to use PostgreSQL's foreign data wrapper feature. By using FDW you can abstract away the multidb handling from django and do it inside the database - now you can use queries that need to use the document -> system relation.

Finally, if your use case allows it, just copying the system data periodically to the local db can be a good solution.