# django with multiple databases and foreignkeys for User

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiple-databases, django-database

Suppose I have a django app on my server, but I wish to do authentication using django.contrib.auth.models where the User and Group models/data are on another server in another database. In Django, my DATABASES setting would be something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'NAME'      : 'my_auth_db',
        'ENGINE'    : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER'      : 'someuser',
        'PASSWORD'  : 'somepassword',
        'HOST'      : 'some.host.com',
        'PORT'      : '3306',
    },
    'myapp': {
        'NAME': 'myapp_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'localuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'localpass',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['pathto.dbrouters.AuthRouter', 'pathto.dbrouters.MyAppRouter']
```

First question: will this work, ie will it allow me to login to my Django app using users that are stored in the remote DB 'my_auth_db'?

Assuming the answer to the above is yes, what happens if in my local DB (app 'myapp') I have models that have a ForeignKey to User? In other words, my model SomeModel is defined in myapp and should exist in the myapp_db, but it have a ForeignKey to a User in my_auth_db:

```
class SomeModel(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    dummy = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    etc.
```

Second question: Is this possible or is it simply not possible for one DB table to have a ForeignKey to a table in another DB?

If I really wanted to make this work, could I replace the ForeignKey field 'user' with an IntegerField 'user_id' and then if I needed somemodel.user I would instead get somemodel.user_id and use models.User.objects.get(pk=somemodel.user_id), where the router knows to query auth_db for the User? Is this a viable approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is: Yes.

What you will need in any case is a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) (The example in the Django docs is exactly about the auth app, so there's no need to copy this code here).

The answer to question 2 is: Maybe. Not officially. It depends on how you have set up MySQL:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases

> Django **doesn’t currently provide any support** for foreign key or many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases.
>
> This is because of **referential integrity**.
>
> However, if you’re using SQLite or **MySQL with MyISAM** tables, there is no enforced referential integrity; as a result, you may be able to **‘fake’ cross database foreign keys**. However, this configuration is not officially supported by Django.

I have a setup with several legacy MySQL DBs (readonly). This answer shows [How to use django models with foreign keys in different DBs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830564/how-to-use-django-models-with-foreign-keys-in-different-dbs/32078727#32078727)

I later ran into troubles with [Django ManyToMany through with multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018277/django-manytomany-through-with-multiple-databases) and the solution (as stated in the accepted answer there) is to set the table name with quotes:

```
class Meta:    
    db_table = '`%s`.`table2`' % db2_name
```

Related questions that might provide some additional information:

[How to work around lack of support for foreign keys across databases in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493241/how-to-work-around-lack-of-support-for-foreign-keys-across-databases-in-django)

[How to use django models with foreign keys in different DBs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830564/how-to-use-django-models-with-foreign-keys-in-different-dbs)

It would be nice if somebody would take all this information and put in into the official Django doc :-)

Comment: This is great info, thanks! From what I see here, it looks like people created all sorts of somewhat complicated solutions, just to be able to access a model using somemodel.user syntax. Since this is just a test app, I think I will use a plain IntegerField and store user_id and have some separate functions that (for example) get the user for somemodel like this: user=User.objects.get(pk=somemodel.user_id). It looks like this will still work. It won't have referential integrity, ie if someone deletes a User then this approach will not automatically delete my SomeModel instances with user_id.

Comment: Yeah, these are complicated workarounds, but all change requests get rejected by Django, so that's what we are stuck with... If performance isn't that much of an issue, the `user=User....` approach is OK, but it will fire an additional query to read the user of each object you are accessing while a spanning ForeignKey could do it in one query (provided the DBs are on the same server)